# Pegar imagen dentro de un input HTML

Tags: html5, angularjs

Tengo una aplicación web donde las personas reportan problemas y tienen la posibilidad de subir imágenes. Al día de hoy para subir esta imagen los usuarios hacen click en un botón para seleccionar la imagen y subirla.
Lo que quiero lograr es omitir este botón y que las personas puedan hacer CTRL+V directamente en un input para cargar la imagen. Es posible lograr esto con un input de HTML? Tengo que crear algún tipo de componente? Hasta el momento en intentado con los input text de HTML pero no funciona.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour]. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Hasta dónde has llegado? ¿Qué problemas te ha dado? Si dejas más datos es más fácil ayudarte :)

Comment: Hola enzo, puedes subir que has intentado o que has averiguado por favor, tendremos mas oportunidad de ayudarte si lo haces, suerte

Comment: No tengo tiempo de escribir una respuesta ahora, lee [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338207/255257) en inglés. Un saludo.

Comment: yo llevo buscando la misma funcionalidad hace bastante, pero no es trivial parece ser. A ver si alguien nos ayuda.
Saludos y gracias!